# Change Data Capture missing changes for a specific record

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, change-data-capture

I have enabled CDC in SQL Server and it generally works well but sometimes the changes are not recorded for some reason. And only for a couple of records. But then if I issue an `UPDATE` from SSMS, the change is recorded.

I'm wondering if it might have something to do with the SQL Server Agent jobs; maybe those jobs fail and because of that the change is not saved?

I have checked the job history in SQL Agent (for `cdc.myDatabase_capture` and `cdc.myDatabase_cleanup`) but couldn't find any failures.

What should I investigate to find the cause of the issue?

SQL Server Details:

```
 Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP1) - 10.50.2500.0 (X64) 
    Jun 17 2011 00:54:03 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Enterprise Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1 <X64> (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) 
 (Hypervisor)
```

Comment: Are you using Get_All_Changes or Get_Net_Changes when you're seeing this?

Comment: CDC processes changes *asynchronously*. Does your logic account for that correctly?

Comment: @SeanGallardy: I'm retrieving data directly from the cdc table

Comment: @JonSeigel: Yes, I know that changes are processed in async mode, but that's not the problem since there are no change records in the cdc table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that the retention period was set to the default of 3 days.

I have extended it to one year using this script:

```sql
EXECUTE sys.sp_cdc_change_job @job_type = N'cleanup', @retention = 525600; --set data retention for 1 year
```